# Django not writing media files to directory in production

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm stumped. I set up a Django site on an Ubuntu server running nginx and it works fine on development. This is not the first or second Django site I've successfully deployed either so I'm basically just copying and pasting settings at this point. Problem is, **my media files aren't uploading, even from the admin**. It says it has, no errors and after saving, it displays the 'link' to the media file. But there's nothing there. I get 404, and if I go to the media directory on the server, nothing was created, be it sub directory or image file.

I checked my media settings and the file paths are correct. `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` correctly points to my media directory. I wondered if it was a permissions error but I've set the media folder to 777 with no luck. However, Django will display media files I upload to the directory directly.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

.

**UPDATE**: So I did server search and saw that my files are being uploaded 2 levels above where they're supposed to be.

My `MEDIA_ROOT` correctly points to `var\www\sk\src\media` but they're being uploaded to `var\www\media`.

Here's my settings.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname('__file__'), '..'))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))  # Add the apps dir to the path

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Try changing the ownership of `media` directory. First `cd` to the parent directory of `media` and run this command: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data media`.

Comment: Did your webserver(nginx/apache) maps media_url to media directory.?

Comment: @xyres I've done this. Didn't work.

Comment: @TarunBehal you mean in the nginx conf?

Comment: yes. @onyeka. it will be like ```location /media/ {
        alias   /home/media/;
    }```.. Also I'm assuming you are using absolute path in MEDIA_ROOT. In case you are composing the path using python, try printing it and see what it gives.

Comment: @TarunBehal My alias is correct. 

Okay so I did a file search on Ubuntu, and I saw that the file is being uploaded to the wrong place. Instead of `/var/www/sk/src/media` it's uploading to `/var/www/media`; Which is weird because Django's MEDIA ROOT is correct..

Comment: @onyeka can you share settings.MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: What are the paths to your settings.py and manage.py files?

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff settings.py is in `/var/www/sk/src/apps/core/settings` (long story, but this has worked for me my last two projects). `manage.py` is `/var/www/sk/src/apps/`

Comment: @onyeka if you open Django shell through manage.py in the same Python environment that your web server uses, then execute ``from django.conf import settings; print settings.MEDIA_ROOT``, does it confirm that it points where it should?

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff  yup it does. First thing i checked/